# after_filter in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to execute an action after the user has logged in. I need something like:

```
after_filter :log_login
```

The method should be called as soon as the user has logged in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does devise have 'callback'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409828/does-devise-have-callback)

Answer (score 1):

You could try inheriting the sessions controller, and add more of your custom login proc.   http://github.com/zmbmartin/devise-roles-user-management.  I use this as an example, it inherit registration controller, not example the same, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409828/does-devise-have-callback/11410032#11410032):

Devise uses Warden behind the scenes and Warden supplies you with a number of callbacks:

https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/callbacks

Have a look at the `after_authentication` callback. That's what you are looking for.

Code:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user, auth, opts|
  # your code here.. 
end
```

You can simply put that code into an initializer (eg. `config/initializers/warden_callback.rb`)