# Does devise have 'callback'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After a user log in, I want to manually log this event and increment a counter column in database.

Is there something like `after_login` in `Devise`? Just as `ActiveRecord`'s `before_save`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Devise uses Warden behind the scenes and Warden supplies you with a number of callbacks:

https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/callbacks

Have a look at the `after_authentication` callback. That's what you are looking for.

Code:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user, auth, opts|
  # your code here.. 
end
```

You can simply create a new initializer file and put the code there. (Like `/config/initializers/warden_callbacks.rb`)

Comment: Where should I write those callbacks?

Comment: You can simply create a new initializer file and put the code there. (Like `/config/initializers/warden_callbacks.rb`)